# how to align html table in the following format

Tags: html

A table row with two columns. One contain a image and another column contain a very large text. The text should start to the right of the image and if goes beyond the image size then the next line should come below the image.

**IMAGE**. Text starts here and then

follows like this

Answer (score 2):

This wouldn't work in columns of a table.

I'd use floats.

### HTML

```
<div class="section">
    <img src="" alt="" />
<p>text</p>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.section img {
    float: left;
    margin: 1em 1em 1em 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use float:left; Then the extra table column is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a table just use the align attribute and set it to left on the image tag.

```
<img src="" alt="" align="left" />Text
```